# Couchbase N1QL query data between two days without time

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I want to retrieve data from a Couchbase bucket with N1QL between two days (from 00:00:00.000 start date time until 23:59:59.999 end date time)

Is it enough to provide the dates without time, like this:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM customer c
WHERE c.start BETWEEN '2017-10-09' AND '2017-10-10'
```

Or do I need to provide the time explicitly:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM customer c
WHERE c.start BETWEEN '2017-10-09T00:00:00.000Z' AND '2017-10-10T23:59:59.999Z')
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couchbase date in ISO-8601 are string comparable. The both queries are fine. Checkout more details https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/datefun.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a view with a map function that convert date to Array like this :

```
function (doc, meta) {
    emit(dateToArray(doc.start), doc);
}
```

and then request the view with [the startKey and endKey filter](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.1/developer-guide/views-querying.html)

Exemple with NodeJS client use [the range method](http://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-node-client-2.4.2/ViewQuery.html#range):

```
const viewQuery = couchbase.ViewQuery.from(nameOfYourDesignDocument, nameOfYourView);

bucket.query(viewQuery.range([2017,10,9], [2017,10,10]), (error, rows) => {
});
```